# question about communication between android device

Tags: java, android, sockets

device A is server, it has sqlite database.

device B, C and D is client, it don't have any database.

those devices i use serversocket,

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT, serverAddr);
byte[] buf = new byte[20];
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

so, my question is after connected. client device is able to access server device like fetchdata() in database? if can, then how to access?

Last but not least, i want to ask the wifimanager that allow multiple client access at a time should declare like what and should place the code at where?

Comment: newbie, click on your profile and click on each of your questions. If one of the answers answered the question for you, click the check mark next to the answer. It will turn green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your question about SQLite, SQLite is not meant to be used in the way you described. See [Connect to a remote sqlite3 database with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318315/connect-to-a-remote-sqlite3-database-with-python) for further information.

Comment: Hadra: so i must use postgresqlite in order to access database through client/server?

Comment: I have never heard of PostgreSQLite. If you could explain what you are trying to achive, we could maybe come up with another solution.

Comment: it was typo error, is postgreSQL. i want client devices able to access to server device database

Comment: I could not find information about running postgreSQL on an android device, and I don't think it was intended to run on a phone. If you can get it to run on your phone though, you can find some ideas for your client-side here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331014/android-os-and-postgresql

Comment: is there has any other suggestion instead of postgresql in order to access server device's (sqlite) database