# Access sqlite database file in a remote server with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

Is it possible to access a sqlite database file in a remote server with PHP? I have enabled read access on the `databse.db` file and tried this:

```
$dbconn = new SQLite3("http://www.foo.com/database.db");
```

but it doesn't work:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to a remote sqlite3 database with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318315/connect-to-a-remote-sqlite3-database-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

SQLITE is not for this operation, but we can do a trick :) .

1. create a RESTful server-api that can be put in the remote server to control what you need.
2. create a RESTful client-api that can be the client you use to connect with the remote RESTful server .

> **NOTE: this is just for fun as by this trick we created server/client api to simulate server/client db using your programming lang and sqlite :)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't connect like this. You can't open the sqlite database which is hosted on remote server, because you may need the update permission of that file.

> So you can download that file in your server parametrically then can
>   connect that file which you downloaded.

Thanks